Update Dataset Connections using Power BI APIs
I am trying to update the connection of a Power BI dataset after uploading the Power BI report.
I have tested the connection and it works when I manually select the connection through the GUI, but I can't work out the parameters I need to send in the post request to do this programmatically. My connection is a cloud connection so i don't think I need a gateway, I don't when I do it through the GUI and the data source type is an Azure SQL Database.
API Endpoint: $url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$workspaceId/datasets/$DatasetId/Default.UpdateDatasources"
My Request: Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url $url -Method Post -Body ($ConnectionDetailsObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10) -ContentType "application/json"
The API Documentation I am working from
I have already created my connection in the Power BI web app. For the purposes of this post lets pretend the ID of that connection is XYZ123.
In my PowerShell script I have created a class which outputs the following JSON for the request body. To the best of my knowledge this is correct, the request does not send an error back, but the data source does not update.
{
  "updateDetails": [
    {
      "DatasourceType": "Sql",
      "ConnectionDetails": {
        "database": "NAME_OF_DATABASE",
        "server": "NAME_OF_SERVER:1433"
      },
      "DatasourceId": "XYZ123",
      "GatewayId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxbc7de9"
    }
  ]
}

The GatewayId value I obtained from inspecting the network tab of the request that's sent when i update the value manually through the GUI. I don't know if this is correct, but it seems like a generic id for the 'cloud gateway'.
What should the body of my request look like to update the connection to the parameter i want?
